# Veggie Burger local to Tulancingo, Mexico

Tags: vegetarian, mexican-cuisine

When I was in Tulancingo, Mexico I had some type of vegetarian burger that I was told was specific to that region. I don't know the Spanish name or what was in it.

Does anyone know what this would be, what it is called, what's in it?

I was there in 1993-94.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We call those sandwiches *guajolotes* [*]; they are specific to to Tulancingo.

> One of the typical foods of the Tulancingo region are *los guajolotes*: buns (similar to a white bread baguette) are halved, filled with refried beans, cheese enchiladas, onions, and salsa. Guajolotes may also sometimes include meat, such as: shredded chicken, ham, sausage, or other delicacies. The assembled sandwich is then pan-fried in butter or oil. [**]

Here is a [youtube video of one being made](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pda0uA8KOIk).

<sub>* Direct translation: turkeys</sub>
<sub>** Roughly translated from wikipedia: [Tulancingo de Bravo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulancingo_de_Bravo#Cultura)</sub>

Comment: +1 for a tough answer! I read this question, was intrigued, and then spent the better part of an hour searching for any evidence of such a sandwich. I came up empty handed, and empty stomached. I'm excited to try one.

Comment: awesome, that's exactly what I as talking about.